# Как использовать Vue.js components на обычном сайте?

Tags: javascript, frontend, vue.js

C сервера при ходит html, при этом из-за требований сео нет возможности писать там vue.js теги и содержимое. По этому хочется отдавать c сервера обычный html с обычным текстом. А уже на клиенте, находить мета в DOM куда должна монтироваться компонента и заменять их нужными для компоненты тегами. Т.е. хочется добавить в компоненту какой нибудь метод типо replase, который вызывался бы для каждой компоненты перед её запуском в Vue и менял бы html... Подскажите пожалуйста, как это можно реализовать, или может есть решение проблемы по лучше? 
**Но серверный рендеринг не подходит и передавать не валидный html местами без текста тоже не вариант..**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Насколько я понял, Вам нужен метод который будет запускаться перед инициализацией компонента, если это так, то у каждого компонента есть опция `beforeMount` которая запускается перед рендерингом вот [Ссылка](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#beforeMount) на основную информацию